# How to dynamically change table status(delivered,send,canceled) with Flask,jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i'm trying to dynamically change the employment state on button click.Basically i have 3 states(Working,Canceled,Finished) and on click i want to change the state of the employee and add him to another table which contains the employees with status(finished,canceled),everything located on the same page.

I'm using flask,Jinja2 without sql

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPetw.png)

Comment: Are you using any database for this...??

Comment: Also provide some relevant information/code.